# Is it OK to add a listener in the build method in a Stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a scrollcontroller which I need to add a listener to do some pagination functions on when the user scrolls down on a listview.

Currently, I create the scrollcontroller and a listener in the `initState`.  I'm doing it there, because the scroll controller is actually a PrimaryScrollController and it needs `context`

```
var _scrollController = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
```

Now I've run into a problem where when my page gets rebuilt for one reason or another the listview will jump to the top.

From what I understand its because on a rebuild, everything is getting rebuild however the `initState` isn't being run.

SO my solution is to move the scrollcontroller creation into the `build` method, which seems to be working just fine.  However, the listener does not work, unless I also move it into the build method.

Is this ok?  Or am I creating potentially many parallel listeners which can increase each time the page gets rebuilt?

Comment: I just ran into the same question. For every call on the build method I'd guess that each time a new listener will be added. Maybe the old ones get disposed?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to listen to the scroll position and do some operations based on the scroll offset you can try a builder named valueListenableBuilder

```
ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget? child) {
                return Row(

                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('$value'),
                    child!,
                  ],
                );
              },
              valueListenable: scrollController.offset,
              child: Container(),
            )
```